# C program will not compile: it shows "lvalue" error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ary[2][3];
    foo(ary);
}
void foo(int (*ary)[3])
{
    int i = 10, j = 2, k;
    ary[0] = &i;
    ary[1] = &j;
    for (k = 0;k < 2; k++)
    printf("%d\n", *ary[k]);
}
```

I tried it with many different compilers but I do not understand why this will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to an expression with an array type.

`ary` inside `foo` is a variable of type "pointer to array of three `int`s".

When you assign to it, you're trying to assign a variable of type "pointer to `int`" to a variable of type "array of three `int`s".

This is invalid because an array is [not an lvalue](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) (6.3.2.1p3):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has `register` storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int (*ary)[3]);


int main()
{
    int ary[2][3];
    int (*x)[3] = &ary[0];
    foo(&ary[0]);
}
void foo(int (*ary)[3])
{
    int i = 10, j = 2, k;
    *ary[0] = i;
    *ary[1] = j;
    for (k = 0;k < 2; k++)
    printf("%d\n", *ary[k]);
}
```

Comment: i'm not want to correction of my code. i interested to knowing why this code behave like that.

Comment: Maybe you dont want but you need it. See the difference and think

Answer (score -3):

In C language array, structure and union always pass by with reference. C language not strictly check reference type and also support implicit casting.

void foo(int (*ary)[3]) this is a syntax of passing a function to a function as reference (call back function). but you trying to assign a value to function which is implicitly cast by c does not matter you pass a array reference. that why its showing lvalue error.

LValue implies that if you assign some value using assignment operator (=) there left side must be a variable but in your case it's a callback reference.

Hope its help.

Comment: `In C language array, structure and union always pass by with reference` - no, they are always passed by value. `not strictly check reference type` - there is no such thing as "reference type" in C language, a pointer to a variable passed to a function is commonly refeerened as a reference. `this is a syntax of passing a function to a function as reference` - no, not at all, it's a normal function declaration that takes a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s as an argument. It's not a "call back function" (or maybe it is - please define that term).

Comment: run this program and you understand is really array passed by value or refernce int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    printf("%d\n ",arr);
    printf("%d\n",&arr);
    checkCallByValueOrRefernce(arr);
    return 0;
}

checkCallByValueOrRefernce(int* arr){
    printf("%d\n ",arr);
    printf("%d\n",&arr);
}

Comment: please refer qsort( ...) which is best example of callback function in C language.